# Chinese input not working Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kde, input-language, chinese

I've tried multiple IMF and IME combinations, ibus and fcitx, ibus-libpinyin, fcitx-sunpinyin, etc. and none work. I've edited the /etc/environment file and ~/.pam_environment.

When I start the ibus-daemon, an icon appears on the taskbar and I can edit preferences and change IMEs, but when I type, nothing changes.

This is how edited the /etc/environment file for ibus

```
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
```

fcitx appears to have no effect at all, despite confirming the process is running. This is how I edited the ~/.pam_environment file:

```
GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
```

Can anyone help? I have Plasma 5.18.5, KDE Framework 5.68, Qt 5.12.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is a *Settings* tool called *Input Method*. Open *Input Method* and use it to set the user configuration "activate Intelligent Input Bus (IBus)".
2. Then remove the input method variables in `/etc/environment` and `~/.pam_environment`. *Input Method* sets those variables. (It also starts ibus-daemon at login, so you don't need to do that manually either.)
3. Reboot

Now open *IBus Preferences*, add "Intelligent Pinyin" and start typing.